# Is it possible to move the descendant of generic class to implementation section?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

I would like to clean concrete classes from interface section, but the compiler doesn't allow to make it.
Whether there is an opportunity to make so that the external code couldn't address to concrete classes?

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils
  , System.Generics.Collections
  , System.Win.Registry
  ;
type
  IMyRegistry<T> = interface
    procedure WriteValue(const Key, Ident: string; const AValue: T);
    function ReadValue(const Key, Ident: string; const ADefVal: T): T;
  end;

  TMyRegistry<T> = class abstract(TInterfacedObject, IMyRegistry<T>)
  strict private
    class var FDefaultReg: IMyRegistry<T>;
    class var FRegistry: TRegistry;
    class var FDefKey: string;
  private
    class function GetDefKey: string;
    class function GetInstance: IMyRegistry<T>; static;
  protected
    procedure WriteValue(const Key, Ident: string; const AValue: T); virtual; abstract;
    function ReadValue(const Key, Ident: string; const ADefVal: T): T; virtual; abstract;
    function GoToKey(const AKeyName: string; const ACreateKey: Boolean = False): Boolean;
    class property InnerRegistry: TRegistry read FRegistry;
  public
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
    class property Default: IMyRegistry<T> read GetInstance;
  end;

  TDefaultMyRegistry<T> = class(TMyRegistry<T>)
  protected
    procedure WriteValue(const Key, Ident: string; const AValue: T); override;
    function ReadValue(const Key, Ident: string; const ADefVal: T): T; override;
  end;

  TMyRegistryFactory = class
  public
    class function GetMyRegistryConcrete<T>: IMyRegistry<T>;
  end;

  //TMyRegInteger = class(TMyRegistry<Integer>)
  //protected
    //procedure WriteValue(const Key, Ident: string; const AValue: Integer); override;
    //function ReadValue(const Key, Ident: string; const ADefVal: Integer): Integer; override;
  //end;

  EMyRegGenericException = class(Exception);
    EMyRegTypeNotSupported = class(EMyRegGenericException);

const
  cCompanyName = 'MyCompany';
  cProgramName = 'MyProgram';

resourcestring
  SRegTypeNotSupported = 'Operations are not supported for values of type "%s"';

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows
  , System.TypInfo;

type
  TMyRegInteger = class(TMyRegistry<Integer>)
  protected
    procedure WriteValue(const Key, Ident: string; const AValue: Integer); override;
    function ReadValue(const Key, Ident: string; const ADefVal: Integer): Integer; override;
  end;    


{ TMyRegistry<T> }

class constructor TMyRegistry<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FDefaultReg := TDefaultMyRegistry<T>.Create;
  FRegistry := TRegistry.Create;
  FRegistry.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  FDefKey := GetDefKey;
end;

class destructor TMyRegistry<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FRegistry);
  inherited;
end;

class function TMyRegistry<T>.GetDefKey: string;
const
  cDefKey = '\Software\%s\%s\';
begin
  Result := Format(cDefKey, [cCompanyName, cProgramName]);
end;

class function TMyRegistry<T>.GetInstance: IMyRegistry<T>;
begin
  Result := FDefaultReg;
end;

function TMyRegistry<T>.GoToKey(const AKeyName: string;  const ACreateKey: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  sDestKeyName: string;
begin
  sDestKeyName := FDefKey + AKeyName;
  Result := FRegistry.OpenKey(sDestKeyName, False);
  if not Result and ACreateKey then
    Result := FRegistry.OpenKey(sDestKeyName, ACreateKey);
end;


{ TDefaultMyRegistry<T> }

function TDefaultMyRegistry<T>.ReadValue(const Key, Ident: string;  const ADefVal: T): T;
var
  tmpReg: IMyRegistry<T>;
begin
  Assert(TypeInfo(T) <> nil, 'Тип не определен');
  Result := ADefVal;
  if GoToKey(Key) then
    if InnerRegistry.ValueExists(Ident) then
    begin
      tmpReg := TMyRegistryFactory.GetMyRegistryConcrete<T>;
      if Assigned(tmpReg) then
        Result := tmpReg.ReadValue(Key, Ident, ADefVal);
    end;
end;

procedure TDefaultMyRegistry<T>.WriteValue(const Key, Ident: string; const AValue: T);
var
  tmpReg: IMyRegistry<T>;
begin
  inherited;
  if GoToKey(Key, True) then
  begin
    tmpReg := TMyRegistryFactory.GetMyRegistryConcrete<T>;
    if Assigned(tmpReg) then
      tmpReg.WriteValue(Key, Ident, AValue);
  end;
end;


{ TMyRegistryFactory }

class function TMyRegistryFactory.GetMyRegistryConcrete<T>: IMyRegistry<T>;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then
    Result := IMyRegistry<T>(IMyRegistry<Integer>(TMyRegInteger.Create)) //<<<  [DCC Error] Unit2.pas(155): E2506 Method ...
  else
    raise EMyRegTypeNotSupported.CreateFmt(
      SRegTypeNotSupported, [PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T))^.Name]);
end;


{ TMyRegInteger }

function TMyRegInteger.ReadValue(const Key, Ident: string;
  const ADefVal: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := InnerRegistry.ReadInteger(Ident);
end;

procedure TMyRegInteger.WriteValue(const Key, Ident: string; const AValue: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  InnerRegistry.WriteInteger(Ident, AValue);
end;

end.
```

If to move a class declaration 'TMyRegInteger' to implementation section, then the compiler reports about an error:
"[DCC Error] Unit2.pas(155): E2506 Method of parameterized type declared in interface section must not use local symbol '.TMyRegInteger'"

in

```
class function TMyRegistryFactory.GetMyRegistryConcrete<T>: IMyRegistry<T>;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then
    Result := IMyRegistry<T>(IMyRegistry<Integer>(TMyRegInteger.Create)) //<<<<<
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You can move class declarations into the implementation section. What's stopping you.

Comment: Looking at your code though, it's not very generic at all. You have to implement separate code for all different types. Which makes generics a bad fit. Method overloading is the way to go here.

Comment: It would be helpful to know **how** the compiler doesn't allow it? Maybe *Unsatisfied forward or external declaration*?

Comment: Shall tell, I simplified a real code from my project a little. When I transfer the class 'TBaseInteger' to the implementation section, the compiler report about an error: "[DCC Error] MyRegistry.pas(880): E2506 Method of parameterized type declared in interface section must not use local symbol '.TBaseInteger'"

Comment: Please edit the question and show the smallest code the produces the error. A [mcve].

Comment: What line of code corresponds to line 880?

Comment: It's going to be this one `Result := IBase<T>(IBase<Integer>(TBaseInteger.Create))`. But we should insist on a decent mcve in the question. The real solution is going to be a proper redesign that doesn't misuse generics in this way.

Comment: I do have a feeling that the Delphi version matters here. That error occurs when you instantiate the type in a different unit and in effect it attempts to inline the instantiated methods and can't see the types declared in the implementation section. So when you edit the question to show the code that fails, you should tell us the Delphi version. I seem to recall the the behaviour has changed in more recent versions. Perhaps I remembered wrongly though. In any case, as I've said, the way forward is to fix the design which is flawed.

Comment: Please please please edit the question so that it includes the code that you want help with!! Please don't post code and then describe the changes that need to be made to produce the condition that you want help with. Please include complete minimal code that demonstrates the error

Comment: I use Delphi XE2. I edited a question. The error arises in case of relocation of declaration of a class 'TMyRegInteger' into implementation section.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I retagged the Q so that it contains the Delphi version. I think you are being caught be a defect that has subsequently been fixed. I still think that your design is poor. I don't see that generics are helpful here since your code is not generic. It is specific to each type

Comment: @David  Earlier I and did - added to declaration of the 'IMyRegistry' interface overload  methods for each new type. Simply it seemed to me
more convenient not to change declaration of the interface, and to make implementation the universal.

Comment: @David  David, many thanks for your notes. You couldn't specify the Delphi version in which defect was fixed?

Comment: Not sure about that, and it might still behave the same in Seattle. I'm doing this from memory. I don't have a compiler at hand to check. Sorry.

Comment: I kind of understand what you want to do, but I agree with @David Heffernan that this design is what is getting you into trouble. In your place I would not have many generic interfaces, but one single interface with a pair of generic methods, like `Set<T>(const aValue: T)` and `Get<T>:T`. However, Delphi does not allow that in interfaces, so in your place I would use a class with that pair of class methods. In the implementation those methods would delegate to work to proper dedicated classes previously and dinamicaly registered to work with particular data types.

Comment: @Alex What's wrong with overloading?

Comment: @David, not sure I understand your question in this context, but I based my suggestion in the original design. It seems to me that the OP wants dedicated classes to work with particular types, but one single way to use them by means of generic interfaces. Like, the OP wants to write `MyRegisty<Integer>.Set(123)` or `MyRegistry<string>.Set('Hello')` or even `MyRegistry<TComponent>.Set(MyButton)`. Considering this assumption I suggested an alternative design to get closer to his/her desires. This design is more extensible than having many overloaded versions of the `Get`/`Set` pair.

Comment: @AlexSC I'm not sure it's more extensible and it results in type switching code executed at runtime rather than compile time switching which is kind of ironic. As a broad rule generic code should be, well, generic. If the type parameters are limited to those that the class knows about, and all instantiations contain all code for all types, then that's a whiffy code smell.

Comment: @AlexSC Perhaps, I not quite understood you, but it seems to me that I do, that you advise: " one single interface with a pair of generic methods". It is possible to exclude the interface IMyRegistry and to use simply the class TMyRegistry, but it seems to me that the error is caused not by use of the Interface, and need to keep all declarations of classes in the interface section.

Comment: @user2448862: you are correct, the problem has nothing to do with interfaces. My suggestion on using a class is just to be able to have generic methods instead of generic interfaces. This is necessary due a limitation of the compiler that does not allow generic methods on interfaces, so one possibility to keep closer to what you seem to want is to replace the interface by a class with two single generic methods. So, instead of writing like `IMyRegistry<Integer>.Set(123)` you would write `TMyRegistry.Set<Integer>(123)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it seems to me that the OP would like to be able to register value handlers for any data type needed in a flexible way. I consider my design more extensible because if a new data type is needed, the design allows to write a new handling class and register it with the registry service (I understand this is what the OP is building) without changing the registry service itself by adding a new pair of methods. It seems to me that the use of generics here serves to prevent type castings, in order to make the use of this service more comfortable.

Comment: @Alex the code has `if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer)` which is specific rather than generic

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, correct, but in my design that hardcoded type handling would be replaced by a `TDictionary` mapping types to a handling classes. So, the OP would be able to add a new handling class at anytime without having to interfere in the registry service code. If tomorrow the OP needs the support for a new data type, s/he would just have to add a new unit, implement a new handling class and register it with the service, not having to touch in the main registry unit. This is why I understand it as more flexible.

Comment: @Alex That's great when designing library code that is intended for extension. I'd argue that for application code that compile time resolution might be cleaner. Anyway, I think the main point is that the code as it stands isn't ideal.