# How to inherit class with generic method?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

There is a class

```
TFoo = class
  function GetValue<T>: T;
  procedure SetValue<T>(AValue: T);
end;
```

The compiler doesn't allow to define methods of this class as `virtual`.
How class

```
TChildFoo = class(TFoo)
```

may use methods of ancestor?

Answer (score 5):

As you have observed, generic methods cannot be virtual. This type

```
type
  TFoo = class
    function Bar<T>: T; virtual;
  end;
```

is rejected with the compiler with the following error:

> E2533 Virtual, dynamic and message methods cannot have type parameters

Your class is declared like this:

```
type
  TFoo = class
    function GetValue<T>: T;
    procedure SetValue<T>(AValue: T);
  end;
```

and you ask how a child class can use these methods. For instance, you can do this:

```
type
  TChildFoo = class(TFoo)
    procedure DoSomething<T>;
  end;

....

procedure TChildFoo.DoSomething<T>;
begin
  SetValue(GetValue<T>);
end;
```

In other words, you can certainly use these methods in the parent class. You just cannot declare them to be virtual and override them.

If you have a parameterized class (rather than a parameterized method) then you can declare virtual methods, and override them.

```
type
  TFoo<T> = class
    function Bar: T; virtual;
  end;

  TChildFoo<T> = class(TFoo<T>)
    function Bar: T; override;
  end;
```

So, these are your options. As to how to solve your problem, that depends very much on what the problem is.

Comment: I look for the "generic-way" solution of a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988147/is-it-possible-to-move-the-descendant-of-generic-class-to-implementation-section?rq=1)
also I try to research AlexS's idea "use a class with that pair of class methods. In the implementation those methods would delegate to work to proper dedicated classes previously and dinamicaly registered to work with particular data types".

Comment: I still don't really understand what the problem is so don't feel confident to suggest a solution. I offered overloaded methods in your other question, but even then I don't think I know enough to judge whether or not that's a good fit for your problem.

Comment: David, thanks for your help and time. Of course you are right. Use of overloaded methods - the easiest and effective way. But let's assume there are 10 methods and it is supposed to use these methods for 10 different types. Unless it not an occasion to look for the generic-solution?

Comment: Generic solution will work well so long as you can write it in a generic way, As soon as you have a bit case statement with run time type switching, it doesn't smell so good.